# Set Email Subject and Body From API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, marketingcloudapi

Looking at the Marketing Cloud API (specifically the REST Reference), I can't seem to find anything that allows you to set the subject and body of an email. Is there some work around or way to do this?

I saw that there is the SimpleEmail Action in the Actions Developer Guide, is there something similar that I missed?

Comment: Are you using the Post Asset route listed here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm

Comment: @EazyE What do you mean? I'm confused on how assets come into play

Comment: The asset routes creates emails in Content Builder.....https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly well documented in the SFMC Content Builder API documentation as @EazyE has stated in comments.

Here is a quick [sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset_model_examples.htm) of the payload for the REST call to build an asset:

```
{
  "name": "NTO Welcome Series Email",
  "channels": {
    "email": true,
    "web": false
  },
  "views": {
    "html": {
      "content": "<!DOCTYPE html><body>This is a simple message.</body></html>"
    },
    "text": {},
    "subjectline": {},
    "preheader": {}
  },
  "assetType": {
    "name": "templatebasedemail",
    "id": 207
   }
}
```

as well as some other [examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset_model_examples.htm) in the documentation.

You would just change `"subjectline": {}` with your text, etc.

You can also check out my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235260/how-to-create-update-email-using-rest-api-salesforce-marketing-cloud) for similar information.